# formula field to access household primary member info on FSC managed package

Tags: households

This is mainly an Financial Services Cloud question.  We created a field named CSS (look up field) in the HH record and the the same CSS (look up field) for the primary HH member client account record.  We would like to create a formula field in the HH record (let's call this Verification Field) that would be true when the HH CSS field is showing the same name as the HH primary member individual account’s CSS field.

I want to create the formula "CSS__c = Primary__c.Account.CSS__c" I think, but I know there is no indication of the primary member accessible in the formulas.  Could this be done in a formula field or would I have to create VF code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, it's too confusing

Comment: I am mainly trying to write a formula in the formula field that would check if a look up field in  the household record (account) has the same value as a look up field in a "person"  record (made up of account and contact record).  The person record is a primary member to the household record, and i can add other person records to the household record in various other roles.  The primary member property falls under the account - contact relationship.  not sure if this help to explain some parts of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for the following formula:

`AND(
   CSS__c = Primary__r.CSS__c,
   NOT(ISBLANK( CSS__c ))
)`